# extract a line from a file using csh

Tags: grep, csh

I am writing a csh script that will extract a line from a file xyz.
the xyz file contains a no. of lines of code and the line  in which I am interested appears after 2-3 lines of the file.
I tried the following code

```
set product1 = `grep -e '<product_version_info.*/>' xyz`
```

I want it to be in a way so that as the script find out that line it should save that line in some variable as a string & terminate reading the file immediately ie. it should not read furthermore aftr extracting the line.

Please help !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[grep](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep) has an `-m` or `--max-count` flag that tells it to stop after a specified number of matches. Hopefully your version of grep supports it.

```
set product1 = `grep -m 1 -e '<product_version_info.*/>' xyz`
```

From the man page linked above:

> -m NUM, --max-count=NUM
>
> ```
>     Stop reading a file after NUM matching lines.  If the  input  is
>     standard  input  from a regular file, and NUM matching lines are
>     output, grep ensures that the standard input  is  positioned  to
>     just  after the last matching line before exiting, regardless of
>     the presence of trailing context lines.  This enables a  calling
>     process  to resume a search.  When grep stops after NUM matching
>     lines, it outputs any trailing context lines.  When  the  -c  or
>     --count  option  is  also  used,  grep  does  not output a count
>     greater than NUM.  When the -v or --invert-match option is  also
>     used, grep stops after outputting NUM non-matching lines.
> ```

As an alternative, you can always the command below to just check the first few lines (since it always occurs in the first 2-3 lines):

```
set product1 = `head -3 xyz | grep -e '<product_version_info.*/>'`
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking to return the first matching line in the file.  If so, one solution is to pipe the `grep` result to `head`

```
set product1 = `grep -e '<product_version_info.*/>' xyz | head -1`
```